# Why this answer was deleted?

Tags: support

In a former question I got the advice to post deleted answers here if I don't understand why they were deleted. I'm not sure how this should work as only users with enough reputation can see deleted posts, but however, I'll try.

Here comes the link to the question: [Avoiding apache to run as root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220030/avoiding-apache-to-run-as-root)

My answer was this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17220070/171318

---

What is wrong with this answer?

Comment: 3 users have decided to delete the answer. Why they decided? Don't know, but there were plenty of comments on it explaining the issues with it.

Comment: @Oded does that warrant deletion however? Downvotes maybe...

Comment: @Bart - I have not said the deletion was warranted. In this case, I don't have enough expert knowledge to tell one way or another. Deletion of answers tends to be reserved to spam/offensive and actively harmful (which may very well be what the opinion about the answer was).

Comment: @Oded Ah true, didn't consider the "actively harmful"....

Comment: @Bart - In this case, since this is a permissions issue involving `root`, I feel that may be the reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this specific case, I believe the users who cast the delete votes felt that the content might do more harm to other people who view the post in the future.

It might get the job done, but it would also add a **huge** vulnerability. I'm sure your heart was in the right place, you *were* trying to help the OP... no doubt about that.

---

Might be an extreme example, but what if someone posted an answer containing code that would perform some "malicious" things - in extreme cases, a downvote might not be enough. We'd want to remove it ASAP as to not let untrained users blindly execute some code they found on Stack Overflow.

---

> **Q:** How can I ensure that port 21017 is open?

> **A:** `sudo service ufw stop` ( completely disable the firewall )

It's an answer, it'll work... but it should never be done. period.

Comment: Note that I didn't asked the question. I thought it was funny that the question itself didn't get any downvotes or delete votes. Only my answer which tells a lot about the security issues. Btw, just teoretical, how will you create a folder that is owned by root without using sudo? You might answer: This isn't necessary and can be / should be worked around in application design. Yes, I'm with you and I wrote this in my answer as well (in bold). But what if the question is just so simple: 'How to create a folder that will be owned by root using the web server?`

Comment: Well It all depends what you are trying to accomplish... you might not actually need the root account but rather a different user who happens to have the correct permissions.. [suEXEC](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html) might work...

Comment: The question could be so simple because the OP simply doesn't grasp the topic too well or understand the implications. IMO, the best answer in a situation like that is to explain the problem and possibly suggest an architectural change as opposed to just providing the OP with a "dangerous" method.

Comment: However, as I've read the post again, I think the most problem might be that the OP - although one could understand this - didn't wanted that the folder should be owned by root. He just wanted to circumvent permission problems. Therefore `root` privileges are just not necessary in this case and this might harm others which don't understand my general answer. Sometimes others understand things in a different manner than the author (me). So your answer might be the explanation I've searched for.

Comment: I supposed architectural change, in bold. However I think the answer was just too much for his simple problem. He just searched for something like `chown -R www-data /path/to/folder` . But I didn't got that it is so simple when writing the answer. However I think the post was good anyway and therefore not deleted myself

Comment: Yep - sadly, some employers still demand quick and dirty fixes as opposed to "doing the right thing". There very well might be some other constraints that we are not aware of preventing him from any big changes.

Comment: `Yep - sadly, some employers still demand quick and dirty fixes as opposed to "doing the right thing".` hehe, why I chuckle? :) ... yeah I know. But however it is not **so** important. Just wanted to have a little feeback on this. Thanks for your time! +1 Can I ask a last question?: Beside from any security and architectural considerations, how would you create a folder that should be owned by root using the webserver? I see only 2 options: Using sudo, or the suexec flag. But note that the second approach will not work for shell scripts. That's why I told sudo is the best solution..